# How to delete a chart using observeEvent in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am using the shiny runtime in flexdashboard.

I would like to hide a chart on button press (`input$updt`), and I was trying this:

````
   ---
title: "Students Data - College of Business"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      orientation: columns 

runtime: shiny
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)
shinyjs::useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

actionButton('updt', 'Update chart')
output$p1 <-renderPlot({ ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point() }, height=800)
plotOutput("p1")

output$p2 <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, disp))+ geom_point()
})

plotOutput("p2")
observeEvent(input$updt, {hide("p1")})


```
````

However, when I click on the button it doesn't hide `p1`

Answer (score 1):

`hide()` needs the `id` of the element that contains the plot, but `renderPlot` doesn't allow setting the `outputId` in `outputArgs`.

A workaround is to use `plotOutput`:

```
library(shinyjs)
shinyjs::useShinyjs(rmd=TRUE)
actionButton('updt', 'Update chart')

output$p1 <- renderPlot({load('p1.RDA') p1}, height=800)
plotOutput("p1")
output$p2 <- renderPlot(expr={ [...code to recalculate p2]  })
plotOutput("p2")
observeEvent(input$updt, {hide("p1")})
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Warning: Error in observeEventHandler: could not find function "hide"`

Comment: I rewrote the question using a reproducible example (sorry I should have done it since the very beginning). It doesn't seem to work tho.

Comment: Just move the call to `useShinyjs` out of `setup` chunk